# Loading properties placed under different folders inside resources in Java

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties

I have few of my properties file placed under resources folder.

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources-
                  prod
                     -> application.properties
                  prod-brand-1
                     -> application.properties
                  prod-brand-2
                     -> application.properties
                  application-default.properties (directly placed under resources folder)
```

In one of my Java class, I am initializing an environment bean which will load properties files using @PropertySource annotation.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application-default.properties",
"classpath:prod/application.properties",
"classpath:prod-brand-1/application.properties",
"classpath:prod-brand-2/application.properties"
})
public class PropertyConfig{
//
}
```

I am able to load **application-default.properties** as it is directly placed under resources folder, but not those which are placed under some directories like **prod,prod-1,prod-2**.

In actual scenario the below has to be replaced with some placeholder and the values(prod,prod-brand-1,prod-brand-2) of which needs to be injected through environment variables.

`@PropertySource({"classpath:prod/application.properties" "classpath:prod-brand-1/application.properties" "classpath:prod-brand-2/application.properties"})`

Should be something like this:-

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:{dir}/application.properties"})
```

Please suggest how can I use placeholder with @PropertySource.

Comment: Don't. Let Spring Boot load them by specifing additional location through the `spring.config.additional-location` property which you can provide at startup.

Comment: How do you know the additional files are not loaded? I had a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526999/initialisation-of-spring-configurationproperties. What is the content of the additional files?

Comment: @hotzst I did test it though Junit test and getting error file "prod/application.properties" not found because it does not exist. When I removed these prod/application.properties,prod-brand-1/application.properties and only have @PropertySource({"classpath:application-default.properties"}) , it works fine and environment has application.properties file in it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not using SpringBoot  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this for files in the same location (resource folders)

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:bar.properties")
})
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

For multiple locations like you said, you can try these codes

```
  @Configuration
    public class PropertiesConfiguration {
         @Bean
        public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
            final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    //        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
            ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);

            final List<Resource> resourceLst = new ArrayList<Resource>();

            resourceLst.add(new ClassPathResource("myapp_base.properties"));
            resourceLst.add(new FileSystemResource("/etc/myapp/overriding.propertie"));
            resourceLst.add(new ClassPathResource("myapp_test.properties"));
            resourceLst.add(new ClassPathResource("myapp_developer_overrides.properties")); // for Developer debugging.

            ppc.setLocations(resourceLst.toArray(new Resource[]{}));

            return ppc;
        }
```

Comment: It will load for sure if foo.properties is placed directly under resources folder.My case is - foo.properties are placed inside multiple directories as I mentioned - prod-brand-1,prod-brand-2 .These directories values should be resolved at runtime through environment variables

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your property sources in same package as your `PropertyConfig.class` file.
Say `src/main/java/com/mypackage/me/prod-brand-2/application.properties.

Then declare your property source like this:

```
package com.mypackage.me.prod-brand-2;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/mypackage/me/prod-brand-2/application.properties")
public class PropertyConfig{
//
}`
```

or use the new `@PropertySources` (not to confuse with `@PropertySource`) annotation: